# How to clean the boot/grub/EFI for new install after using a corrupted install media?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

tl;dr:
Used a corrupted (SquashFS Errors at the beginning of the install) install media USB A, but the residue from the 1st corrupted  install still appearing after switching to another USB B. How to clean it? Thanks

Long version:
So I had Win10 and was trying to install Ubuntu for dual boot. I had a SD card that was used on Nintento Switch, it had a folder "Nitendo" in it. I burned the iso to it with etcher on Win10, and it corrupted my sd card (this is another issue, google "etcher read only windows unrecognized" for other people with the same issue), so I used Rufus to burn again and it seemed fine now with the content viewable in explorer. When I boot with the media, there was the menu that let you choose "Try or install ubuntu", then either before or after that appeared, there were some quick error lines that include "Nintendo" in it. Afterwards it begins the installation but stuck with errors of "SQUASHFS error ... zlib decompression, SQUASHFS error ... failed to read block"

So I burned iso to another "never used on Nintendo SD card" with Rufus directly and booted again. But I still got the quick errors with Nintendo before/after the "Try or install" menu and the same SQUASHFS error afterwards.

So it probably cached some corrupted installer inside the boot/grub/EFI/etcetc? How can I make a clean install without affecting the Win10 side?

Thanks

Comment: Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
  For other releases' hashes, like lubuntu, see:
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: if your ubuntu iso file in good state you can use unetbootin from windows to make boot menu entry for ubuntu iso

Comment: If you encountered *squashfs* errors on your media; you should not trust that install at all, as the installer you used may have been corrupted, anything it did may also be corrupted; and you should have thus stopped the moment you detected corruption on the install media (*software only works if its corrupted; you were told of corruption thus it may not work properly due to corruption!*)  You provided no Ubuntu specifics (product/release), but I'd just re-install asap & ensure you perform ISO validation & write checks before hand for your *unstated* Ubuntu product/release/ISO